# Indy UDP Server very low speed

Tags: sockets, c++builder, indy

I'm using RAD Studio 10.2 with Indy 10, a component `IdUDPServer`.
To test the speed of UDP connection, I installed the program [UDP Test Tool](http://startrinity.com/VoIP/NetworkTester/NetworkTester.aspx).

My code for checking speed of the UDP server:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;

int readCounter = 0;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Memo1->Clear();
    TIdSocketHandle *SocketHandle = IdUDPServer1->Bindings->Add();
    SocketHandle->IP = "127.0.0.1";
    SocketHandle->Port = 14014;
    IdUDPServer1->Active = true;
    if (IdUDPServer1->Active == true) {
        Memo1->Lines->Add("Сервер стартовал");
        Button1->Enabled = false;
        Button2->Enabled = true;
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Memo1->Clear();
    IdUDPServer1->Active = false;
    IdUDPServer1->Bindings->Clear();
    if(IdUDPServer1->Active == false) {
        Memo1->Lines->Add("Сервер остановлен");
        Button1->Enabled = true;
        Button2->Enabled = false;
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::IdUDPServer1UDPRead(TIdUDPListenerThread *AThread, const TIdBytes AData,
          TIdSocketHandle *ABinding)
{
    readCounter++;
    Edit1->Text = readCounter;

    char* szBuff = new char[AData.Length];
    memset(szBuff, 0, AData.Length);
    BytesToRaw(AData, szBuff, AData.Length);
    Memo1->Lines->Add(ToHex(AData));
    Memo1->Clear();
    delete szBuff;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I use the `readCounter` in the method `IdUDPServer1UDPRead` for later comparison with the number of packets sent via the downloaded test utility, but the counters do not match. It can be seen that the component `IdUDPServer` is very late.

[image: screenshot]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TIdUDPServer::ThreadedEvent` property is `false` by default.  That means every time the server receives a data packet, your `OnUDPRead` event handler is synced with the main UI thread *synchronously* via `TThread::Synchronize()`.  That will, of course, slow down the server's overall performance.

To make your server react to the UDP packets more quickly, you need to make your `OnUDPRead` event handler return control to `TIdUDPServer` more quickly.  That means setting `ThreadedEvent` to `true` to skip the `TThread::Synchronize()` call, do not access the UI at all (or, at least, update the UI *asynchronously* using `TThread::Queue()` or `TIdNotify`), and remove any useless code that is slowing down your handler (you are allocating and filling a `char[]` buffer that is not being used for anything at all, so that is just wasted overhead).

For example, if you are using a Clang-based compiler:

```
// make sure ThreadedEvent=true...
void __fastcall TForm1::IdUDPServer1UDPRead(TIdUDPListenerThread *AThread, const TIdBytes AData, TIdSocketHandle *ABinding)
{
    ++readCounter;
    TThread::Queue(nullptr,
        [=]() {
            Edit1->Text = readCounter;
            Memo1->Lines->Add(ToHex(AData));
        }
    );
}
```

Otherwise, if you are using a classic compiler:

```
// See "Handling Anonymous Method Types in C++":
// http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/How_to_Handle_Delphi_Anonymous_Methods_in_C%2B%2B

class TMyQueueProc : public TCppInterfacedObject<TThreadProcedure>
{
private:
    int m_counter;
    TIdBytes m_bytes;

public:
    TMyQueueProc(int ACounter, const TIdBytes &AData) : m_counter(ACounter), m_bytes(AData) {}
    INTFOBJECT_IMPL_IUNKNOWN(TInterfacedObject);

    void __fastcall Invoke()
    {
        Form1->Edit1->Text = m_counter;
        Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add(ToHex(m_bytes));
    }
};

// make sure ThreadedEvent=true...
void __fastcall TForm1::IdUDPServer1UDPRead(TIdUDPListenerThread *AThread, const TIdBytes AData, TIdSocketHandle *ABinding)
{
    ++readCounter;
    TThread::Queue(NULL, _di_TThreadProcedure(new TMyQueueProc(readCounter, AData)));
}
```

Or:

```
#include <IdSync.hpp>

class TMyNotify : public TIdNotify
{
private:
    int m_counter;
    TIdBytes m_bytes;

protected:
    void __fastcall DoNotify()
    {
        Form1->Edit1->Text = m_counter;
        Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add(ToHex(m_bytes));
    }

public:
    TMyNotify(int ACounter, const TIdBytes &AData) : TIdNotify(), m_counter(ACounter), m_bytes(AData) {}
 };

// make sure ThreadedEvent=true...
void __fastcall TForm1::IdUDPServer1UDPRead(TIdUDPListenerThread *AThread, const TIdBytes AData, TIdSocketHandle *ABinding)
{
    ++readCounter;
    (new TMyNotify(readCounter, AData))->Notify();
}
```

Comment: Remy, thank you very much, you really helped. I will hope for your help with the Indy library in a difficult time!